# How to sort only the values of an object in JS?

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have a JS object defined as this `{0: 3, 2: 2, 4: 1}`, and I want to sort only the values, and leave the keys in tact. What I mean is that after the object is sorted, the end result should be `{0: 1, 2: 2, 4: 3}`, so only the values change their places and not the keys.

I have the following code segment:

```
let list = {0: 3, 2: 2, 4: 1};
Object.keys(list)
      .sort((a, b) => list[a]-list[b])
      .reduce((obj, key) => ({
          ...obj, 
          [key]: list[key]
      }), {});
```

But, it doesn't seem to work. In fact, it doesn't seem to sort it at all. Any ideas how to achieve what I want in JS?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order

Comment: Use a `Set` which guarantees key order

Comment: Why not use an `Array`?

Comment: @tinker objects are only guaranteed to retain order in native ES 6 environments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could sort the values, the keys stays in ascending order, because object's keys who are integers are sorted by default. Later assign the sorted values to the keys.

```js
var list = { 0: 3, 2: 2, 4: 1 },
    values = Object.values(list).sort((a, b) => a - b),
    result = Object.assign(...Object.keys(list).map((k, i) => ({ [k]: values[i] })));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This is very nice.  I'd written my own solution (using Ramda) and was going to see how easily it ported to plain JS, when I saw this much better one.  well done!

Answer (score 0):

There are more elegant solutions involving 3rd party libraries (need `zip`, `partition`, etc.), but this should get you there:

```
let foo = {0: 3, 2: 2, 4: 1};

// here we'll just sort the keys and values independently and then
// recombine them
let keys = Object.keys(foo).sort((a, b) => a - b);
let vals = Object.values(foo).sort((a, b) => a - b);
let result = keys.reduce((acc, k, i) => (acc[k] = vals[i], acc), {});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution more

```
let list = {
   0: 3,
   2: 2,
   4: 1
}

let values=Object.values(list).sort()

Object.keys(list)
  .sort()
  .reduce((obj, key, i) => ({
      ...obj,
        [key]: values[i]
  }), {});
```